Swift UI testing: staticTexts is not being updated when I go to a new view
I have a simple app with two views, a home page and a main page. I have a button on the home page that goes to the main page via logic like this:
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingMain) {
    MainView()
}

I'm writing a basic Swift UI test to press the "Start" button on the home page, and then check that I am on the second page (view). When I run the test, in the simulator I see the button pressed and the main view come up.
However, if I try and check for an object (for example in staticTexts), it only shows the objects on the first view. It is as if the state is not updated somehow. I tried waiting a few seconds but it doesn't help.
Does anyone have any ideas?
func testExample() throws {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    app.buttons["Start"].tap()
    XCTAssert(XCUIApplication().staticTexts["Back to home page"].waitForExistence(timeout: 2)) // FAILS
    
    for staticText in  app.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex{
        print(staticText.label) // SHOWS TEXT FROM FIRST PAGE
    }
}


As usual, I managed to solve the problem shortly after posting. I'll put in info here why in case someone runs in to the same issue.
My main problem was that I was using staticTexts[] instead of buttons[]. Changing that fixed it. However my confusion was because I was seeing strings from the 1st view in staticText.
It seems that if you do a transition via fullScreenCover it will still contain the staticText items from the first view, since I guess it is still technically on the screen.

Correct, covers do not dismiss what they exist on top of.
